# Remove header from bibliography pages

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex

I use this LaTeX code to add a bibliography section:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bp}
```

The first page looks fine. It contains the **Bibliography** title, no header and a list of citations. However on the next page is a header with the title of the previous section. Is there a way to remove this header?

[alt text http://imagebin.ca/img/9u-wk68W.jpg](http://imagebin.ca/img/9u-wk68W.jpg)

Comment: Can you post an example document?

Comment: It might be worth asking this at superuser.com, too.

Answer (score 8):

The first page is typeset with pagestyle plain. The following pages have the pagestyle of the rest of the document, which (apparently) you modified using fancyhdr.

In the [documentation of fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf), see the \markright and \markleft commands, which can modify the headers in your document. Probably a \markright{} can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it gave me an idea how to solve the problem. I initially thought I want something to change the layout if `\bibliography`, but it turns out the problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sorry, I've realized that the fact that the first page of a section is without the heading was explicitly defined in the style I was using. I thought it was `\bibliography` that was clearing the header on the first page.

I've solved it by adding this after the last section:

```
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
```

(`\clearpage` was necessary, because otherwise it removed headers also from the last section)